# Do summary stats on columns across multiple data frames and store results in a table

Tags: r, loops, indexing, multiple-columns, lapply

Can you guys help me with a loop?

I am a little familiar with `for (){}` loops but obviously not enough:)

```
mean20neg <- mean(negative20$`19/20`)
mean20pos <- mean(positive20$`19/20`)
sd20neg <- sd(negative20$`19/20`)
sd20pos <- sd(positive20$`19/20`)
```

If I want to run these
in a loop (and put the results in a table at the end) for multiple other dataframes like negative21/22 and positive21/22 how can I address the columns?

Other point which could help how can I unlist a data.frame? because now these are for some reasons a list and I can't use `mean(negative20[2])` to adress the column.

Thanks

```
xxx <- CEPSird2[ ,c("year","id_zewo","ird2")]
id_zewo <- as.numeric(CEPSird2[CEPSird2$year==2019, c("id_zewo")])

result <- c()
for (i in id_zewo) {
  value <- xxx %>%
    filter(id_zewo %in% i, year > 2018) %>%
    select(3)
  Wert1 <- value$ird2[2]-value$ird2[1]
  Wert2 <- value$ird2[3]-value$ird2[2]
  Wert3 <- value$ird2[4]-value$ird2[3]
  result <- rbind(result, c(i,Wert1,Wert2,Wert3))
}
ÄnderungAbsolut <- as_tibble(result)
colnames(ÄnderungAbsolut) <- c("id_zewo","19/20","20/21","21/22")

positive20 <- ÄnderungAbsolut[ÄnderungAbsolut$`19/20`>0, ]
positive20 <- positive20[order(positive20$`19/20`, decreasing = TRUE), c("id_zewo","19/20")]

positive21 <- ÄnderungAbsolut[ÄnderungAbsolut$`20/21`>0, ]
positive21 <- positive21[order(positive21$`20/21`, decreasing = TRUE), c("id_zewo","20/21")]

positive22 <- ÄnderungAbsolut[ÄnderungAbsolut$`21/22`>0, ]
positive22 <- positive22[order(positive22$`21/22`, decreasing = TRUE), c("id_zewo","21/22")]

negative20 <- ÄnderungAbsolut[ÄnderungAbsolut$`19/20`<0, ]
negative20 <- negative20[order(negative20$`19/20`), c("id_zewo","19/20")]

negative21 <- ÄnderungAbsolut[ÄnderungAbsolut$`20/21`<0, ]
negative21 <- negative21[order(negative21$`20/21`), c("id_zewo","20/21")]

negative22 <- ÄnderungAbsolut[ÄnderungAbsolut$`21/22`<0, ]
negative22 <- negative22[order(negative22$`21/22`), c("id_zewo","21/22")]
```

Answer (score 0):

Most cases when you think you need a `for` loop in R, you don't need one, but you may need `lapply()` and lists.

1. Put all your data frames in a list
2. Use `lapply()` to extract a specific column from each data frame in that list
3. Use `lapply()` to compute your summary stats for the extracted columns
4. Unlist the results into vectors
5. Make a table out of those vectors, displaying the results.

Note that I used three example data sets (`iris`, `mtcars` and `trees`) to make this code reproducible.

```r
df_list <- list(iris, mtcars, trees)

# extract e.g. the first column of each data set
extracted_cols <- lapply(df_list, purrr::pluck, 1)

# result is yet another list
# compute summary stats, use `lapply` because columns are still inside a list

mean_value <- lapply(extracted_cols, mean) |> unlist()
#> 5.843333 20.090625 13.248387

sd_value <- lapply(extracted_cols, sd) |> unlist()
#> 0.8280661 6.0269481 3.1381386

# put them in a table

results <- data.frame(id = 1:length(extracted_cols), mean_value, sd_value)
#>   id mean_values sd_values
#> 1  1    5.843333 0.8280661
#> 2  2   20.090625 6.0269481
#> 3  3   13.248387 3.1381386
```

On your question:

> how can I address the columns?

and

> how can I unlist a data.frame?

I know what you mean by "unlisting", you want to get the column not as a data frame with 1 column, but as a vector, so you can do numeric calculations on that column without the functions complaining.

- `[ ]` on a data frame returns another data frame
- `[[ ]]` on a data frame returns the column(s) as a vector
- `$` is a special form of `[[ ]]`, using the column name, and has the same outcome: a vector.

If your data frames are in a list: using `lapply()`, you can access specific columns in each data frame like this:

```r
lapply(df_list, `[[`, 1) # gets first column of each data frame
```

`purrr::pluck()` is a generalized and safer alternative to the `[[` operator and nicer to type and read, that is why I used it instead (but this is an opinion).

```r
lapply(df_list, purrr::pluck, 1) # does the same but safer
```

In both variants, the code gets the first column of each data frame contained in `df_list`. It returns a list, where each element contains the first column of the corresponding data frame.

You can replace `1` with any number you like, or a string, like `"19/20"` for your data example. The string makes sense if all columns have the same name in the different data frames. If they don't have the same name, but are at the same position, you can use the number to index the position. If your relevant columns are neither at the same position nor bearing the same name, maybe you should do some data cleaning before hand to achieve this.

Comment: Thank you very much this helps me a lot.

Comment: But I still have another question. Instead of mean in the lapply() function how can I put there normal calculations?
```Anteil20neg <- sum(cumsum(negative20$`19/20`)/sum(negative20$`19/20`)<0.75)
Anteil20pos <- sum(cumsum(positive20$`19/20`)/sum(positive20$`19/20`)<0.75)```
I want to calculate these but how do I apply them to the lapply function?

Comment: inside `lapply()`, you need a function. You can declare a function beforehand which does your calculation, or you can create an anonymous function inside the `lapply()` call. Note that there are many ways how to do this, the package `purrr` ships an `~` operator to declare anonymous functions on the fly. I would just go with a simple anonymous function: `lapply(extracted_cols, function(x) sum(cumsum(x) / sum(x) < 0.75))`

Comment: Great Thanks A lot.
If I need now to create all these steps (from the first answer) again, how do I create a loop for this?
Lets say these dataframes (negative20, positive20, ...) were for Data1(here in the example its "ird2" which would need to be replaced) now I need to do the same steps for Data2, Data3, ... which all come from the same main Dataset. Here is How i got it know can you help me with this? @uke
I added the code to the my question so you can have a look hopefully you can help me:)

Comment: honestly, I can not quite follow. At this point, it would be beneficial if you try and adapt your code to be minimal and reproducible. Remember, I do not have any of your data sets on my computer. Also, on StackOverflow there is a "one question per question" rule, meaning if we diverge from the topic of the main question, please open a new question. But if you think, this is the same topic (which I think), please adapt your code so I can understand what you are doing. describe your goal and the data you are working with, find an equivalent example dataset or paste the `dput()` of your data.

Comment: Sorry, I try to explain it.
In ÄnderungenAbsolut are 3 columns with the difference between two years (see colnames), id_zewo can be ignored. Now I try to split each of the columns up into the ones >0 (positive) and <0 (negative), where I get 6 different vectrors, 3 positive and 3 negative ones. 
These 6 vectors (which I need for a following step (regarding my first question)) are from a subset of my main Data (CEPS). The subset is "ird2", which I "extracted" in the first line. Now I need to do the whole process also for ird1, ird3, etc so the whole code would be in a loop. Is this possible?

Comment: Let me know if you need more informations to help me @uke

Comment: Yes, thanks for the explanations. it seems like this is material for a new question. Please post a new question and provide a minimal reproducible example in that question, e.g. `dput(head(CEPS))`. Then describe your goal, a desired outcome (how the results table should look like), and describe your current approach. If your example is truly reproducible and also minimal, you will surely get an answer quickly. If you want, you can paste the link to the new question here so I can follow up.

Comment: I opended a new question, maybe you can help me there @uke. Thanks.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77452338/do-a-loop-for-multiple-data-frames-to-receive-a-table-with-values-from-differen