# Do a loop for multiple data.frames to receive a table with values from differen data.frames

Tags: r, loops, lapply

I need to loop this whole code for multiple data.frames. This is now for CEPSird2, but I would need it also for CEPSird1, CEPSird3, ... and others (see below to have an outtake of the data)

What I would like to get is: I have a data.frame (i.e CEPSird2) where I am interested in the "ird2" column (the column of the other data.frames are equal and have values over multiple years from 2015 to 2022, but I only need the ones >2018). In the first loop, I create a new data.frame (ÄnderungAbsolut) with the absolute differences between two years ("19/20","20/21","21/22"). Then I split each of these 3 columns up to have only the positive and negative values, and receive 6 vectors (positive20, positive21, negative 20,....), two for each year. Afterwards I want to calculate for each of these 6 vectors different numbers (mean, sd, gini, and a function(x)) and summarise them in a table (results). The 3X9 table is now for the 3 years ("19/20","20/21","21/22") and the 8 numbers I am interested in. Now I need this same table just not for ird2 in CEPSird2 but for ird1 in CEPSird1 and ird3 inn CEPSird3 etc. Great would be if the rows would have the years infront instead of 1,2,3 like it is now and also where they are from (ird2 ord ird3 etc)

I know it is a lot but maybe someone can help me. Thanks a lot.

```
Test <- data.frame(year= rep(c(2018,2019,2020,2021,2022),6),
          id_zewo= rep(c(1:6),each=5),
          ird2=runif(30, min = 10000, max = 30000))

Test.id_zewo <- as.numeric(Test[Test$year==2019, c("id_zewo")])

result <- c()
for (i in Test.id_zewo) {
  value <- Test %>%
    filter(id_zewo %in% i, year > 2018) %>%
    select(3)
  Wert1 <- value$ird2[2]-value$ird2[1]
  Wert2 <- value$ird2[3]-value$ird2[2]
  Wert3 <- value$ird2[4]-value$ird2[3]
  result <- rbind(result, c(i,Wert1,Wert2,Wert3))
}
ÄnderungAbsolut <- as_tibble(result)
colnames(ÄnderungAbsolut) <- c("id_zewo","19/20","20/21","21/22")


positive20 <- ÄnderungAbsolut[ÄnderungAbsolut$`19/20`>0, ]
positive20 <- positive20[order(positive20$`19/20`, decreasing = TRUE), c("id_zewo","19/20")]

positive21 <- ÄnderungAbsolut[ÄnderungAbsolut$`20/21`>0, ]
positive21 <- positive21[order(positive21$`20/21`, decreasing = TRUE), c("id_zewo","20/21")]

positive22 <- ÄnderungAbsolut[ÄnderungAbsolut$`21/22`>0, ]
positive22 <- positive22[order(positive22$`21/22`, decreasing = TRUE), c("id_zewo","21/22")]

negative20 <- ÄnderungAbsolut[ÄnderungAbsolut$`19/20`<0, ]
negative20 <- negative20[order(negative20$`19/20`), c("id_zewo","19/20")]

negative21 <- ÄnderungAbsolut[ÄnderungAbsolut$`20/21`<0, ]
negative21 <- negative21[order(negative21$`20/21`), c("id_zewo","20/21")]

negative22 <- ÄnderungAbsolut[ÄnderungAbsolut$`21/22`<0, ]
negative22 <- negative22[order(negative22$`21/22`), c("id_zewo","21/22")]

df_listpos <- list(positive20,positive21,positive22)
df_listneg <- list(negative20,negative21,negative22)
  extracted_pos <- lapply(df_listpos, purrr::pluck, 2)
  extracted_neg <- lapply(df_listneg, purrr::pluck, 2)
  
mean_pos <- lapply(extracted_pos, mean) |> unlist()
mean_neg <- lapply(extracted_neg, mean) |> unlist()
  sd_pos <- lapply(extracted_pos, sd) |> unlist()
  sd_neg <- lapply(extracted_neg, sd) |> unlist()
    gini_pos <- lapply(extracted_pos, Gini) |> unlist()
    gini_neg <- lapply(extracted_neg, Gini) |> unlist()
      cumsum_pos <- lapply(extracted_pos, function(x) sum(cumsum(x)/sum(x)<0.75)) |> unlist()
      cumsum_neg <- lapply(extracted_neg, function(x) sum(cumsum(x)/sum(x)<0.75)) |> unlist()
results <- data.frame(id = 1:length(extracted_pos), mean_pos, mean_neg, sd_pos, sd_neg, 
                      gini_pos,gini_neg, cumsum_pos,cumsum_neg)
```

Here the tail of my data. The years range from 2015 to 2022 and id_zewo is just the corresponding number for the values in the rows. I filter ird2 out because CEPSird2,CEPSird3,... have other variables I don't need now. If it would simplify the code I can safe CEPSird2 already with the 3 variables ("year","id_zewo","ird2") I need so I could jump this step.
The ÄnderungAbsolut data.frame gives me then for example the difference of id_zewo 500 bewteen 19/20,20/21 and 21/22.

```
tail(CEPSird2[c("year","id_zewo","ird2","ird3")])
     year id_zewo    ird2    ird3
3859 2022     500  129302  802312
3861 2022     502 4399508 4658553
3867 2022     514  871262       0
3869 2022     518   86635       0
3871 2022     521  128275       0
3872 2022     522       0       0
```

Comment: cheers for including the tail of your data. even better practice would be to declare an object that is containing only this tail data you shared with us, und base your example calculations on that object so that we can just copy paste your code and it is running! At the moment this is still not possible. what is intriguing me, is how you create `CEPSird2` and the other data frames out of `CEPS` (you mentioned in an earlier question that there was a whole data set that you break up in many). Could you please include the output of e.g. `dput(head(CEPS))` and the manipulations you do to it?

Comment: I changed my code in the question, now you can run it. But maybe you don't get nice values in "results", b/c the numbers are runif. 
The CEPS has columns like $ird1, $ird2, $ird4, and CEPSird2 is just the $ird2 column that I need but for each variable I need to clean out some rows b/c they have wrong values but they are not the same for the different variables (ird2, ird1, and so on) so I create a new data.frame (CEPSird2). It could be of course possible to create a new data.frame with the columns from the different subdatas (CEPSird2,CEPSird1,CEPSird4,...) so they are all in one together@uke

Comment: Hope this helps you:) and me

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is indeed helpful. I have to ask one more question: How come that these `ird` columns contain wrong values, and is it possible to replace those wrong values with `NA`s or would this be misleading? I would prefer the `NA` method because it allows us to keep `CEPS`, because each column will have the same amount of observations, only that some miss more and others less. Would this be a sensible approach to your data?

Comment: My bad, they are not wrong values it's because maybe they have NA in 2019 and in the next year in 2020 they have a value and this misleads my results of my analysis. That's why I remove these rows that distrot this data but as I said for ird1, ird2 most are the same rows but not 100%.

Comment: would you know a method how I can loop this code in this example for also Test2, Test3 and so on? @uke

Comment: Hi @dan, I condensed your calculations into a `dplyr` pipeline, and added code to run this pipeline on many data frames. Please look at my answer to see if this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

A generic approach to apply identical manipulations to a list of dataframes and combine the results. `d1` and `d2` being your dataframes:

```
    library(dplyr)

    d1 <- data.frame(year = 2018, value = rnorm(3), dummy_a = 'junk')
    d2 <- data.frame(year = 2019, value = rnorm(3), dummy_b = 'other junk')
    
    list(d1, d2) %>%
      Map(f = \(d){## some data processing, e. g.: tidyverse stuff
        d %>%
          select(year, value) %>%
          mutate(value = value * pi)
      }) %>%
      do.call(rbind, .)
```

output:

```
    ##   year      value
    ## 1 2018  3.2673407
    ## 2 2018 -1.0875516
    ## 3 2018  0.2297448
    ## 4 2019 -1.6449955
    ## 5 2019 -0.4552625
    ## 6 2019 -3.8103155
```

Comment: Could you maybe explain what you did after the ```list(d1, d2) %>%```. What the different codes stand for and what they do?

Comment: `Map` (or its enhanced version `map` from {purrr} applies a function to each element of a list and returns a list of the manipulated items. In above case, list items are and remain dataframes which are then combined using `do.call(rbind, list_of_dataframes)` for performance reasons. The payload within `Map(...)` is in above case an exemplary set of [{dplyr} expressions](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/dplyr.html).

Comment: what is this `\(d)` notation? I have seen it around some times but do not know what it means.

Comment: Yes would be great to know:)
But how would it look like in my example? Because I have kind of two block I need too repeate and they need to be consequitive. @uke

Comment: @uke: it's a shorthand to define a function: `\(x) ...` is equivalent to `function(x) ...`

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote your calculations into `dplyr` code. A lot of `for` loops were avoided because of its `group_by` capabilities. In short, this allows us to calculate separate summary stats for e.g. every `year`, or every `id`. That allows us to skip the tedious creation of many small intermediate data frames.

This is the whole code.
All calculations are contained in the `data_wrangling` part. See a code breakdown below.
Everything else is needed to apply these calculations to many data frames.

```r
library(dplyr)

# create example data frames
test1 <- data.frame(year = rep(c(2018:2022), 6),
                    id_zewo = rep(c(1:6),each = 5),
                    ird1 = runif(30, min = 10000, max = 30000))

test2 <- data.frame(year = rep(c(2018:2022), 6),
                    id_zewo = rep(c(1:6), each = 5),
                    ird2 = runif(30, min = 100, max = 1000))

test3 <- data.frame(year = rep(c(2018:2022),6),
                    id_zewo = rep(c(1:6), each = 5),
                    ird3 = runif(30, min = 1, max = 100))

# create a list containing these data frames
df_list <- list(test1, test2, test3)

# one way to save some hassle is to rename 
# all `ird1, 2, 3... ` columns to "value".

# get old colnames
new_colnames <- names(test1)
# inject colname "value" instead of "ird..."
new_colnames[3] <- "value"

# apply column renaming to all data frames
df_list <- lapply(df_list, setNames, new_colnames)

# data wrangling starts
# defining a function that does all the work
# to be called later inside `lapply()`

data_wrangling <- function(x){
  x |>
  group_by(id_zewo) |>
  filter(year > 2018) |>
  mutate(year_diff = value - dplyr::lag(value)) |>
  ungroup() |>
  mutate(positive_diff = year_diff > 0) |> # This is a helper, allowing us to use group by
  group_by(positive_diff, year) |>
  summarise(mean = mean(year_diff),
            sd = sd(year_diff),
            n_below_3rd_quartile = sum(cumsum(year_diff) / sum(year_diff) < 0.75))
  #gini = Gini(year_diff)) # I dont know what package Gini is from
}

# apply data wrangling steps to all data frames
results <- lapply(df_list, data_wrangling)

# show results
results
```

**Results**

A list containing one results table per entered data frame.

```r
# [[1]]
# # A tibble: 7 × 5
# # Groups:   positive_diff [3]
# positive_diff  year   mean    sd n_below_3rd_quartile
# <lgl>         <int>  <dbl> <dbl>                <int>
#   1 FALSE          2020 -9098. 5046.                    2
# 2 FALSE          2021 -5562. 3180.                    3
# 3 FALSE          2022 -6050. 4858.                    2
# 4 TRUE           2020  7869. 4573.                    2
# 5 TRUE           2021  1950. 1915.                    0
# 6 TRUE           2022  6578. 6156.                    1
# 7 NA             2019    NA    NA                    NA
# 
# [[2]]
# # A tibble: 7 × 5
# # Groups:   positive_diff [3]
# positive_diff  year   mean    sd n_below_3rd_quartile
# <lgl>         <int>  <dbl> <dbl>                <int>
#   1 FALSE          2020 -150.  157.                     1
# 2 FALSE          2021 -348.  297.                     2
# 3 FALSE          2022  -36.5  NA                      0
# 4 TRUE           2020  596.  194.                     2
# 5 TRUE           2021  246.   40.5                    1
# 6 TRUE           2022  234.  145.                     3
# 7 NA             2019   NA    NA                     NA
# 
# [[3]]
# # A tibble: 7 × 5
# # Groups:   positive_diff [3]
# positive_diff  year   mean    sd n_below_3rd_quartile
# <lgl>         <int>  <dbl> <dbl>                <int>
#   1 FALSE          2020  -9.30  5.64                    1
# 2 FALSE          2021 -18.5  15.2                     2
# 3 FALSE          2022 -50.4  15.1                     3
# 4 TRUE           2020  21.0  29.8                     0
# 5 TRUE           2021  13.5  12.6                     2
# 6 TRUE           2022  47.1   9.07                    1
# 7 NA             2019  NA    NA                      NA
```

#### Data wrangling part

Let's see what is done inside our custom data wrangling function. Let's take `test1` as example data.

```r
test1 |>
  group_by(id_zewo) |>
  filter(year > 2018) |>
  mutate(year_diff = ird1 - dplyr::lag(ird1)) |>
  ungroup() |>
  mutate(positive_diff = year_diff > 0) |> # This is a helper, allowing us to use group by
  group_by(positive_diff, year) |>
  summarise(mean = mean(year_diff),
            sd = sd(year_diff),
            n_below_3rd_quartile = sum(cumsum(year_diff) / sum(year_diff) < 0.75))
#gini = Gini(year_diff)) # I dont know what package Gini is from
```

Here is a step by step summary.

1. `group_by(id_zewo)` is grouping the data by ID. This ensures that later, the `diff` is calculated separately for each id (what you tried to achieve with the `for` loop at the beginning of your code).
2. Filter data to exclude years below 2019
3. Create a column `diff` that contains the difference to `ird` of the previous year. Because we grouped by `id`, this diff is calculated separately for each `id_zewo`.

   Here is how the table looks like at this step:

```r
test1 |>
  group_by(id_zewo) |>
  filter(year > 2018) |>
  mutate(year_diff = ird1 - dplyr::lag(ird1))

# Output:
# A tibble: 24 × 4
# Groups:   id_zewo [6]
# year id_zewo   ird1 year_diff
# <int>   <int>  <dbl>     <dbl>
# 2019       1 23248.       NA 
# 2020       1 19966.    -3282.
# 2021       1 23271.     3304.
# 2022       1 21833.    -1437.
# 2019       2 28372.       NA 
# 2020       2 16062.   -12310.
# 2021       2 10383.    -5678.
# 2022       2 23761.    13378.
# 2019       3 19182.       NA 
# 2020       3 27070.     7887.
```

Note that our grouping worked, because in each `id` group, the diff starts with `NA` for the `year` 2019, because there is no year before 2019.

5. Remove grouping

   We do this, because the following summary statistics shall be computed by `year` and not by `id`. We want the `mean` for 2019, for 2020, etc. But first we need to create a helper column.
6. Create a helper column that indicates whether the diff `year_diff` is positive or not.
7. Group by this helper column `positive_diff` and `year`, so we get summary statistics in the next steps for each separate year **and** separately for positive and negative diffs.
8. Calculate summary statistics. You can adapt the code to include your `Gini` function which I did not find.

**Data Wrangling Output** for `test1`

```r
# # A tibble: 7 × 5
# # Groups:   positive_diff [3]
# positive_diff  year   mean    sd n_below_3rd_quartile
# <lgl>         <int>  <dbl> <dbl>                <int>
# 1 FALSE          2020 -9098. 5046.                    2
# 2 FALSE          2021 -5562. 3180.                    3
# 3 FALSE          2022 -6050. 4858.                    2
# 4 TRUE           2020  7869. 4573.                    2
# 5 TRUE           2021  1950. 1915.                    0
# 6 TRUE           2022  6578. 6156.                    1
# 7 NA             2019    NA    NA                    NA
```

How to read this output:

- the summary stats for positive diffs are in rows where there is `TRUE` in the col `positive_diff`
- stats for negative diffs are in rows where `positive_diff` is `FALSE`.
- last `NA` row can be ignored. It is here because `group_by(positive_diff)` considers `NA` to be a group by its own.